# Reading a file in C

Tags: c, file, input

My friend and I are working on a project, and we need to read input from a file in C.

The file looks like this:

```
15 25 200
3 10
17.99 22.99 109.99
100 2 4
5.99 99.99 20.00 49.99
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
3.99 5.99 7.99 8.00 5.00 5.00 5.00 6.00 7.00 9.99
5
```

I need to read the file line by line, and set each value equal to a different variable. For example, the first value on the first line must be set to the variable preSalePrices, the second value doorPrices, and the third preSales. I need help figuring out how to specify the number of values on each line. For example, how do I tell the program to get three values on the first line, but only two on the second line? Then four values on the fifth line, and so on.

Here is my code, but it just crashes:

```
int main() {
    float preSalePrices, doorPrices;
    int preSales;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = ("C://Users//Jake//Desktop//Charity Ball//auction01.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%f %f %i", &preSalePrices, &doorPrices, &preSales) != EOF) {
        printf("%f, %f, %i", preSalePrices, doorPrices, preSales);               
    } 
}
```

I've looked all over the internet and I can't find anything related to this specifically.

Comment: don't scan whole lines like that into the variables - read each line one variable at a time.

Comment: read a line, split it using space as a delimiter.  see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: You should be getting compilation warnings since your code is missing the call to `fopen()`.  You should be checking the return value from `fopen()` too, though the test would not help with the function call missing — `fp` gets a non-null pointer to `"r"`.

Comment: Since each value has to go in a separate variable (are you sure about that? No arrays?), you are obliged to specify the variables in declarations and in appropriate calls to appropriate functions.  You should probably use `fgets()` to read the lines and `sscanf()` to parse them.  Each line will have a separate `sscanf()` to process it (because you have to pass different variables each time).  You need to rethink your code structure and possibly the data structure in the file.

Comment: shouldn't the path-separator be double backslash? `\\ ` instead of `//`? (and single forward slash on unixes of course)

Answer (score 2):

If you always know the number of values in each line, you can just ignore the end-of-lines and read the values one by one.

If the end-of-lines are important the easiest way is to read each line separately (e.g. `fgets`) and then read the data from there, with `sscanf`.