# Can I read in an int from a textfile in C, if I know there will be (space)###(space)

Tags: c, input

Is it possible in C, when reading a text file, to take in an integer value of unknown size (assuming it will fit in an int) by the fact it will have a space before the number and after the number.
Eg. 363 865
I would like to store 363 and 865 each as there own int variables.
With that being said is it possible to do this if I add characters?
Eg. Take the numbers and store them as variables! 363 865 
So do the same thing but not touch the text.

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%d %d", &a, &b);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651535/reading-a-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many numbers are there then you can use [`fscanf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) -

For example if 2 numbers are there-

```
fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&num1,&num2);  // fp - file pointer ,num1 and num2 are integer variables
```

Or if you don't know how many numbers are there 
 you can use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)-

```
fgets(buffer,1000,fp);       // buffer char array of size 1000 and fp file pointer
```

and use function [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to tokenize `buffer` and convert it into number using [`atoi`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) .

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` format specifier will eat leading whitespace, this will work as well with `fscanf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = " 363 865 ";
    int a, b;
    if (sscanf(str, "%d%d", &a, &b) == 2)
        printf("%d,%d\n", a, b);
    else
        printf("Bad input\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
363,865
```